# How do I add a div class to my site's header.php file so that I can insert logo to my site's main menu?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I'm trying to add a div class to my wordpress site's main menu by editing it's header.php file. This div class is meant to allow me to insert a logo onto the left-hand side of the menu for my site.

This is the div class I want to insert to the header.php (or at least that's what I think I want...I'm not entirely sure)

```
<a class="logo-container" href="/">
<img src="x.png" alt="x" class="top_logo">
</a>
```

Here's my header.php file

```
?>
<!doctype html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="https://gmpg.org/xfn/11">

    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php esc_html_e( 'Skip to content', 'hi' ); ?></a>

    <header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <?php
            the_custom_logo();
            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
                ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <?php
            else :
                ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            endif;
            $hi_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $hi_description || is_customize_preview() ) :
                ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $hi_description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'hi' ); ?></button>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->

    <div id="content" class="site-content">
```

I tried sticking my html code before and after this line of code here:

```
<nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'hi' ); ?></button>
```

but it just creates a div class before the menu bar div class instead of being inside it.

Instead, I want the div class to be inside the "menu-main-container" class found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouDTw.jpg

Answer (score 0):

```
<header id="masthead" class="site-header">
        <div class="site-branding">
            <a class="logo-container" href="/">
            <img src="x.png" alt="x" class="top_logo">
            </a>
            <?php

            if ( is_front_page() && is_home() ) :
                ?>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <?php
            else :
                ?>
                <p class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></p>
                <?php
            endif;
            $hi_description = get_bloginfo( 'description', 'display' );
            if ( $hi_description || is_customize_preview() ) :
                ?>
                <p class="site-description"><?php echo $hi_description; /* WPCS: xss ok. */ ?></p>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </div><!-- .site-branding -->

        <nav id="site-navigation" class="main-navigation">
            <button class="menu-toggle" aria-controls="primary-menu" aria-expanded="false"><?php esc_html_e( 'Primary Menu', 'hi' ); ?></button>
            <?php
            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'theme_location' => 'menu-1',
                'menu_id'        => 'primary-menu',
            ) );
            ?>
        </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
    </header><!-- #masthead -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I get an error "syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file" when I try that...for line "<a class="logo-container" href="/">..not sure why...but I think that code won't put the class inside the div I want which I would think is farther down the code where the php stuff is for the nav menu.

Comment: try again i have edited the code.. my bad it was a mistake

Comment: The code seems to put the x above the menu...giving it the same effect as when I tried putting it before and after the line of code I mentioned in the original post